# R package openXLSX & Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results

Tags: r, excel

When exporting tabular data with very small p.values, we noticed that some rows were mistakenly replaced by 0.0000000000 in the obtained excel file instead of very small power of 10 in the -200 ... _300

The following link tells us that the smallest Excel limit is 2.2250738585072E-308 but we observe errors for numbers like 1,21408E-288 or 1,21408E-288
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)
We could confirm this by serially dividing 2.2250738585070E-208 by 10

serial division by 10 to reach the published limit

[image: serial division by 10 to reach the published limit]

exported text table using R code (note small numbers in 10E-293 and -288 in third column.

[image: exported text table]

exported xlsx file version of the same table using [openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html)  R code where small numbers are replaced by 0.0000000000 (dot instead of comma separator)

[image: resulting excel file with errors]

MS Excel corrects at opening but uses the wrong decimal separator

[image: excel corrects the mistake leading to wrong decimal separator and inconsistent number for my locale settings]

Does someone know what the limit is for Xlsx export so that we can convert such numbers to 0?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question by clearly telling us what your data pipeline is (e.g. R to Excel or vice-versa), and also give sample data at each step which passes and also other data which fails?

Comment: the issue was known and is better described **[here](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/132)** but the proposed solution did not work for me because I could not (yet) install the dev-version of the package that should do fine.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was finally known and was solved by installing the developer version 3.1.6 of the openXLSX package (refer to the **[github page](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx)** for install and look at **[issue 132](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/132)**